# How to display department_id, job_id and the average salary for each job classification in each department?

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery, correlated-subquery

I have tried this but obviously it will only give mt the average salary for all the departments not each job classification

```
SELECT e.department_id, e.job_id, (SELECT avg(salary)
                                   FROM employees)
FROM employees e
GROUP BY department_id, job_id;
```

Comment: can you please give your table stucture and output uoi want ?

Comment: Why do you use group by if your aggregate function is in a subquery?

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya I dont have an output but my tables are departments, employees jobs
I am using the HR schema on ORACLE SQL

Answer (score 2):

Do you want the department's avg salary? Do a correlated sub-query:

```
SELECT e.department_id, e.job_id, (SELECT avg(salary)
                                   FROM employees e2
                                   where e2.department_id = e.department_id)
FROM employees e
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want this (if your aim is get average salary for couple department_id / job_id):

```
SELECT e.department_id, e.job_id, avg(e.salary)
FROM employees e
GROUP BY e.department_id, e.job_id;
```

If you want average only for department_id you can write:

```
SELECT e.department_id, e.job_id, 
    (SELECT avg(e1.salary)
    FROM employees e1
    where e1.department_id = e.department_id)
FROM employees e
GROUP BY e.department_id, e.job_id;
```